# writing a directive for validating image url

Tags: angularjs

this is the first directive I'm writing for AngularJS.
I want to check if an image url inserted into a text input is valid.

this is what I have so far:

```
angular.module('directives', [])
.directive('imageUrlVerify', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
            var image = new Image();

            scope.$watch(function() {
                if (ctrl.$viewValue) {
                    image.src = ctrl.$viewValue;

                    if (image.complete) {
                        scope[attrs.imageValid] = true;
                    } else {
                        scope[attrs.imageValid] = false;
                    }
                } else {
                    scope[attrs.imageValid] = false;
                }
            });
        }
    }
})
```

and I use it:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="imageUrl" placeholder="Image URL..." data-image-valid="imageOk" image-url-verify>
```

This is actually working, but as my first directive I want to make sure that I'm doing things the right way...

am I missing something ?

EDIT: following @Josh-David-Miller 's answer I came up with this:

```
angular.module('directives', [])
.directive('imageUrlVerify', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: true,
        scope: { url: '=', imageValid: '=' },
        template: '<input ng-model="url" placeholder="Image URL..."/>',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var image = new Image();

            scope.$watch('url', function() {
                scope.imageValid = false;
            });

            element.on( 'blur', function() {
                image.src = scope.url;
            });

            image.onload = function() {
                scope.$apply(function() {
                    scope.imageValid = true;
                });
            };

            image.onerror = function() {
                scope.$apply(function() {
                    scope.imageValid = false;
                });
            };
        }
    }
})
```

and use it like:

```
<input image-url-verify url="imageUrl" image-valid="imageOk" />
```

does it look better? anywhere else to improve?

Comment: The modified code looks much better, but this won't be very responsive. After typing in a correct URL, the user will still have to wait for the image to download and decode before the field is marked valid. From UX perspective, it may not be optimal.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I follow the purpose your directive, but it can be cleaned up a bit.

First, reusable directives should have an isolate scope, so they can't mess with anything they're not supposed to. In your case, it actually makes the code simpler.

Second, the $watch statement isn't watching anything. $watch takes a first parameter that is either an string expression to be evaluated against the current scope, of a method to be executed with each digest to determine if a value changes. Your method doesn't return anything, so there's nothing to watch. Your code actually just executes the same piece of code on every digest. Perhaps you can elaborate on what you're going for here.

Lastly, your verification will occur with every keystroke, which is probably not very helpful. I changed it to run when the focus leaves the input element.

Here's the updated code:

```js
angular.module('directives', [])
.directive('imageUrlVerify', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    replace: true,
    scope: { url: '=', imageValid: '=' },
    template: '<input ng-bind="url" placeholder="Image URL..." valid="imageValid" />',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      var image = new Image();

      element.on( 'blur', function() {
        image.src = url;
        imageValid = url != "" && image.complete ? true : false;
      });
    }
  }
})
```

And then its usage is changed to:

```html
<input image-url-verify url="imageUrl" image-valid="imageOk" />
```

Some of these design choices are preferences and some will depend on your specific usage, but absent either, this is how I would rewrite your directive.

Comment: the purpose of the directive is to check if an image url is valid before displaying the image and submitting the url to the backend. should I be doing it in a different way ? how do I invalidate a form that includes this directive ?

Comment: @GalBen-Haim So the user is providing a server-side image location? If so, this sounds like something the app should ask the server to verify. `image.complete` is only set to `true` after the image has been downloaded and decoded, so this is pretty inefficient. Can you provide some context?

Comment: The user fills a form, one of the fields is an image url (any image). if the url is a valid image it is displayed. once the form is submitted, if the url is valid, it is also posted to the backend. I want to do this client-side to alert the user if the URL is invalid.

btw - Your directive doesn't work. I changed url and imageValid to scope.url and scope.imageValid,   but scope.url is undefined.  can't I just use ng-model like with a standard input field ?